# Should I monitor my child's internet usage?

Tags: safety, age-appropriate, computer, internet

This question was inspired by this one: https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/2698/how-do-i-monitor-what-my-kids-do-on-the-computer which was deemed off topic.

Hopefully this is more on topic as I'm not interested in the specifics of how to monitor what my kids do on the internet.  But what general approach I should take, and what approaches others have used?

Comment: +1 for a question that I'm also very interested in! Not relevant yet with my toddler, but I'm wary of what he'll come across once he wants to surf.

Comment: Consider putting your _thoughts so far_ into an answer and just leave the first two paragraphs in the question.

Comment: @Torben thanks, moved my own answer.  It's also not quite relevant for me yet, but expecting to have to give this some thought in the future.

Comment: The (UK) term is 'e-safety'. Some resources: http://www.kidsmart.org.uk/parents/ http://www.childnet.com/parents-and-carers/hot-topics/keeping-young-children-safe-online

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Yes,** I think that children's online activities should be monitored **but I don't think it's feasible in practice** except for very young children. Older kids will always find a way to circumvent your control – but the good news is that they get more computer-literate in the process :-)

To me it's the same as having someone supervise small children at the playground or any other public place. The purpose is to make sure that they're not hurting themselves or others, aren't hurt by others, and know/learn how to engage their social environment properly. The problem is that it's much harder to supervise a computer without being intrusive.

- Blocking is effective but also very obvious and easy to circumvent, so it would only work as long as the kids aren't technologically literate enough to get around your block.
- Monitoring is probably only feasible as long as it's invisible to the user. Once your kids suspect that you're monitoring their actions, they might just use other means (a computer at school or a friends' place). Another drawback with monitoring is that you've got to spend time evaluating the log files, which can be quite tedious.

#### Alternative suggestion

Instead of blocking and/or monitoring, approach the computer and the Internet the same way you would the playground:

Why do you trust your 16-year-old to act responsibly while unmonitored? Because you've spent enough time *together* and you've taught by example and by word what's right and wrong. You've seen that your child is able to fend for himself and can recognize and avoid bullies and bad places, and that he's not a bully himself.

This is much harder to do at the computer – who'd want to spend hours surfing Facebook or other "juicy" sites with their dad?! And with all the mobile devices existing today, and crawling into classrooms too, this will likely become even harder in the future. I don't have a future-proof solution! :-(

One approach I've seen (which works for the time being) is to **have a computer in the living room** or family room, or make sure in other ways that nobody can hide out in front of the computer. Whatever you do at the computer needs to be okay to do while others are watching - otherwise, what exactly are you doing?

I've recently moved my computer from a "work" room into a "work" corner of the living room, and even for me it's much more social now. I highly recommended it. Just now I realized that it incidentally supports the *"show, don't tell"* philosophy. I'm not sure that's feasible for the kids when we only have one computer there, though. You could have a few laptops and a house rule that they're only used in the living room, but that might be hard to enforce consistently (especially if the kids have laptops for school, which they could then simply use outside the home).

Comment: +1 for living room - this beats "technical solutions" much more, and makes using the computer a social something. Don't use monitoring software on your kids, you're not hanging camera's all around your house either (I hope)

Comment: If you control the gateway, you control the internet, as far as clients are concerned. The only way around that is to find another route to the internet. It does require a certain level of technical skill though.

Comment: @afrazier, you're venturing into IT territory now. We should continue _that_ over at superuser.com instead.

Comment: I'd second the 'living room' answer for a laptop. For older kids with smartphones the situation is more complex since they don't even need to be at home to get to the interwebs. In that case you just have to make sure they have the nous and confidence to manage themselves on the web. My rule of thumb is that if you wouldn't send it on a postcard, don't email it or post it on the web.

Comment: I would also suggest computer use in a public area. Alternatively, an older child doing homework on a laptop could be allowed to work in their room with the condition that they have to leave their door wide open.

Comment: @afrazier The work around for parental-blocked Internet is to use the Internet somewhere the parents aren't controlling it.

Comment: it is certainly possible to control what happens on your PC (windows family safety is an example).  If they use someone else's PC you can do nothing

Comment: While having a PC in the living room can help, its not a total answer. At some point you are going to want to leave them home alone, or just be outside in the garden or something. Also, what happens if they want to concentrate on something on the computer at a time when you are watching TV?

Comment: "Older kids will always find a way to circumvent your control" - a whitelist at the gateway level is pretty bulletproof, but can be a pain to manage.

Comment: @ZenGuy true, I wouldn't want to have to manage that whitelist :-) but even so, "older kids" would easily find other connections that you can't your whitelist on - using their mobile device on a friend's network, or some public access point.

Comment: The computer in my house was in the living room, and I still managed to view plenty of porn the moment I hit puberty and desired to do so.  Mostly by viewing it at night after I knew my parents were in bed, but there were a multitude of other times when I had unsupervised access to it.  And that's ignoring the fact that my friends were all but forcing me to view porn before I even reached the age I was interested in it at their houses and other locations.  Better to accept the kids will have uncontrolled internet access if they want it and focus on preparing them to use it wisely.

Answer (score 20):

Do you monitor the books they read from the library? Do you monitor the music they listen to on the radio? Do you monitor the TV and Movies they watch? Do you monitor what they say and hear from their friends? If so, then I'd say yes... it's just yet another stream of content.

Honestly, the easiest way to monitor, is to put the computer in a communal space with the screen facing away from the wall. Then when they're on the computer, be in the room, even if it's only occasionally. I'm sure you'll recognize the quick window focus change in a panic they do when they realize you walked in on something they knew they shouldn't have had up. :)

Answer (score 12):

In answer to my own question, this is one approach I've thought about, and it would be age dependent, so something like:

- 0-7 years, no unsupervised access.
- 8-13, unsupervised access allowed to a white list of sites, everything else blocked.
- 14-16, no blocking, but everything logged, so I can keep an eye on them.
- 16+, no blocking, no logging. (Presumably I should respect their privacy at some point, and if I've had any success as a parent, they'll know about proxy servers by now).

Comment: I don't think logging is a good thing at any age unless you suspect something is very wrong. It's somewhat like reading a diary; needed in some cases, but not to be done without cause. I'd simply reduce the blocking as they are older.

Comment: +1 for the idea of having levels of decreasing strictness as the child gets older. Whether the supervision is feasible in the first place is another matter - see my answer for my thoughts on that.

Comment: I like the decreasing supervision, as to logging I don't see a problem with that.  You can always just review the sites they are going to, not the individual pages - so you at least know where they are going.

Comment: logging might very well be your first hint that something is up... assuming you have a decent tool for filtering that log.

Comment: I agree with the idea. The Internet is a very, very... bad... place. Visiting random at 4chan can scar for life.

Comment: For white listing, consider a router with OpenWrt. Off topic, I know, but FYI.

Comment: An important point to keep in mind if you want to do something like this is that those age ranges are just a guideline and you should adjust them based on your child's behaviour, maturity, level of comfort with the Internet etc. It's something fairly obvious to most people, but I think it should still be mentioned.

Comment: I disagree with this.  If you think a 13 year old child will settle for a restricted whitelist (which by nature of being a white list would have to a minuscule part of the internet) your kidding yourself.  What will happen is they will have their friends show them everything on their computers. The only difference is that they will be afraid to tell you what they are doing online and you won't be able to talk them through it.  You won't know they have a FB page so you won't know what their doing on it etc.  The result is there less prepared to use the internet responsibly later in life.

Comment: ...and that is even before you get into the fact that maintaining a whitelist that is at all useful to the child is practically impossible given the nature of the internet, every day the child will be coming to you with a half dozen new sites they heard about that they can't get to.  Or the fact that by the age of 13 I could have circumvented most whitelist or blacklist options my parents were capable of attempting. Or the hostility you will get for not allowing them to have access every single peer they know has and the harm it will do to your relationship to be so over controlling.

Answer (score 11):

As an elementary school librarian, I was responsible for talking with students and parents about computer use. We focused a great deal about the very scary presence of predators on the internet. We encouraged parents to constantly talk with their children about what they are doing on the internet, who they are talking to, what sites they are visiting.

I know many parents felt like they were intruding, spying on their kids; however in reality just as it is our job as parents to monitor who our kids play with and what homes they are spending time in, it is also our job to monitor their internet usage.

I love the idea of keeping all use in family areas of the home. Not only does it help you be aware of what they are doing, it makes the dialogue that much easier - if your child is right there and comes across something questionable, they can ask.

It is also important to talk with your kids about internet safety in a similar way you talk with them about not taking a ride from strangers. Teach your child that sharing information that seems innocent can be dangerous. Every year there are cases of predators posing as children on the internet gathering crumbs of information from children for months before making their move. Children should never reveal their last name, phone number, address, school name - also, teach your children to carefully check the screen names of their friends - sometimes predators change one character and pose as a friend.

I know when my daughter is old enough to use the computer it will always be in the presence of myself or my husband so we are there to guide her internet use.

Good luck to all parents navigating internet use - it is a different world than when we were kids our parents only needed to monitor the neighborhood.

Comment: "it is a different world than when we were kids" - you are so right, and it can be scary.

Comment: No down vote, but I don't think the world is that much different. That's an illusion.

Comment: It is different if you are old enough that there was not Internet when you were a child. Admittedly there were similar dangers from strangers, but they were local and easier to monitor. The Internet allows for dangerous adults to masquerade as children to gain children's trust.

Comment: @Doug: The world might not be that different. The difference is that the world is closer to your home, and potential "predators" are closer and larger in numbers.

Comment: Unknown and unnamed "predators" figure much higher on the perceived risk scale than they do as actual risks, it comes down to "reporting bias" in the media.  This reporting bias means our children are (collectively) expected to live a decade less than us because society has become so risk averse that they don't play outside.  In reality on the internet peer actions like cyber bullying are much more likely to ruin (and have taken) more lives.  I'm not saying that we should ever ignore 'stranger danger' but the actual risks should outweigh the imaginary.

Comment: I want to strongly second what @JamesSnell said.  Actual statistics show that in reality a child is *significantly*  more likely to harmed by their own father, or a teacher or other trusted figure, they are of even encountering some  random "predator", either in person or the internet.  If your worried about predators your better off doing background checks on any adult that spends time around your child then any of the things you discuss.  In fact the "Stranger Danger" teaching is actually discouraged now as children ended hiding from police and not asking for help when in actual danger.

Answer (score 9):

I exposed myself to a lot of terrible things whilst growing up and spending a lot of time on the Internet - things that I feel still affect me today. I had absolutely no supervision on Internet access from the age of about 8, although I greatly wish I did so I might not have seen and done what I have.

I believe the best solution is in putting the computer in a family living space so that they can expect someone to see what's on their screen at any given time.

**Talk to your kids!** Ask them personally what they're doing but don't be accusative, act interested. They will either happily tell you about whatever game they're interested in, or they'll act coy because they're hiding something. While they are young enough to be exposed to bad things or be at risk of bad people, I expect these signs will be obvious.

**Never** resort to technical means. These will only annoy your child and prove to them that you do not trust them or what they do on a computer. More than likely they will incorrectly flag websites they need to use for homework, too, AS WELL as giving you a completely false sense of security. They are easy to bypass (doubtless your child is or will be smarter than you at computers before you realise it ). Also, smart phones are ubiquitous these days which provide easy unrestricted Internet access, either by tethering or a neighbours open WiFi.

Technical solutions are far too passive a means of 'securing' your child's access to the Internet and, as I say, are easily bypassed yet at the same time teach your child to keep silent about their activity, when they must be encouraged to be open and share with you what they're doing.

Comment: This. You can't imagine how tech savvy some 12-13 year olds are nowadays. Don't let it end in a cat-and-mouse-game of blocking and circumventing!

Answer (score 4):

I use Trend Micro software on all of the computers in my house, which also includes internet filters. As suggested in other posts, I started out with very strict rules on which websites the computers could allow. My kids (now 12 and 10) each have their own logins so that I can set up different rules for each.

We regularly discuss what types of sites they are allowed to access. If a site is blocked that they believe they should be able to access, I'll allow/not allow it after hearing their argument. The software also blocks ads that could be an issue as well.

I think the most important thing is to have open discussion about what is acceptable and the consequences of accessing content that is not allowed (loss of computer privileges etc.)

The software offers the ability to log sites that are visited, but I've never looked that deeply at it.

My rule of thumb is to let the kids know that I will trust them until they break that trust. So far, it's worked well as they even ask before watching questionable shows on television.

Answer (score 4):

I would also consider time caps like you would consider for television: perhaps 1-3 hours per day depending on the age.

Would be glad to hear in the comments what caps parents are using and how are they enforcing them.

Comment: It's easy for us, we have two computers that my son could use.  One is basically the main home machine, that I mainly use but its downstairs in the "office" and no one is allowed there unsupervised.  Second computer is my wife's laptop that she uses a lot - we allow it to be used since it's generally in the room we are in so there is supervision.  I don't see this changing for a long while.

Answer (score 3):

Monitoring and/or blocking can work with younger children, and I don't see any problem with monitoring as long as you tell your children that they are being monitored. However at some point between the ages of 10 and 14, depending on intelligence, motivation and just how tightly you lock down the PC, they are going to be able to get to places on the Net you would probably rather they didn't. Even if your security is watertight, they will be visiting friends whose computers are not as tightly locked down, and there are these devices called thumb drives. These days an 8GB thumb drive costs around $10 and can hold several hours of HD movies.

So rather than try to create a watertight seal around the bad bits of the Internet, I think you have to think about your own fears about what you are trying to protect them against, and what other strategies you can use. I'll outline predators and porn as examples here because they seem to be the commonest concerns.

Against predators, I think the best option is to warn them there are bad people on line, and teach basic security and safety. Never give out your full name or address on line. Never trust anyone (unless they are an established physical-world friend) to be who or what they say they are. (My son's circle of friends at primary school went through a period of hacking each others Club Penguin accounts by shoulder-surfing, which also helped teach some basic lessons on security).

Against porn, you need to acknowledge that it exists, and make your own views clear (whatever they are). You also need to get the idea across that its got about as much connection with "real" sex as a James Bond movie has with real spying. Emphasise that if they have any worries about anything they do happen to see then you will listen and answer questions without judging them, the same as you would on any issue with sex.

Answer (score 1):

If your child is below 12 years of age, I believe you should still monitor his or her internet usage.  As a parent, it is our responsibility to guide our children with the choices they make in using the internet.  It is not about helicopter parenting, but I think this is still crucial time where your child still needs proper guidance.  When your child reaches teen years, you can start giving him or her independence, but from time to time check their activities, so you can properly guide them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think monitoring kids is a good idea. What he is interested in on the internet is determined by his daily habit, so cultivating his good interests and hobbies is useful than monitoring him.

Comment: Welcome to the community Haseen and thanks for your contribution.  You must be addressing this from the perspective of not limiting time, but rather encouraging non-computer related activities so computer time doesn't become too much?  What about making sure a six year old doesn't stumble upon pornography or an adolescent doesn't give an online predator her information?  On SE it is really nice to add a little to tell the reader where your viewpoint is originating and what your experience in the matter is - or provide sitations to back your answer as reliable.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple to filter your home internet by setting OpenDNS as your DNS server on your router. You can then have [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/index.php) block or allow specific sites or classes of sites, as you wish. You can also have all internet use logged if you choose. As long as you keep control of your router, they are unlikely to be able to change this, and if they do, you'll know. You'll also know your kid is being sneaky, and this behavior is likely in other areas of his life.

In my own home, I've set up OpenDNS to limit what they might accidentally stumble across, I've taught them about personal safety and security as well as appropriate behavior while using the Internet, and I loosely monitor the time they spend on the computer. I do not log anything. I feel like education with a bit of a safety net is the way to go.

Comment: Welcome to the community Marc and thanks for your contribution.

Comment: Unfortunately this is really easy for kids to circumvent. Changing the devices DNS server to 8.8.8.8 gets around the blocks.

Comment: @Adam Mills - Not when I switch DNS servers at the router and block all DNS requests but OpenDNS on port 53. If I was really concerned, I'd set up user accounts on their computers and require an administrative password to make system changes. We all run Linux, so that's a three minute task. I've never needed to do that because I'm lucky enough to be able trust my kids. I run everything through OpenDNS so they don't get hit with something they can't ever un-see.

Comment: @Marc - unfortunately most DNS servers run on more than port 53... Its better than nothing. But its still trivial to use 8.8.8.8 on port 5353 for example...

Comment: @Adam Mills If you're that worried, you have bigger problems, and you should perhaps eliminate internet access altogether. One step short of that is to create a limited user account to prevent changing any network settings. That, too, is trivially easy, but very difficult to bypass.

Comment: @Marc - We use koalasafe.com

Comment: @Adam Mills - The splash page looks interesting, but I'm  an "open source" kind of guy. I'd accomplish the same end for less money but certainly more trouble using a dd-wrt based router, OpenDNS, and a limited user accounts if I felt I needed that much control. Fortunately, my kids never tried to push boundaries too far, so I had OpenDNS to stop them from accidentally coming across the wrong stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I've seen online for control kids internet usage, especially older kids ran something like the following:

Tell them that everything they have free access to the internet to research, play, and learn. However, What they look at will be tracked, and the logs reviewed. If they find something unsuitable, there will be an open frank discussion with both parents on why they feel it's necessary to view the material.

Nothing scares a teenager more than being faces with questions from Mommy on why they googled something perverted.

But, for younger kids, we just limit they times they have any access, using it as a reward after homework and chores are complete. The computer they use is in the living room and facing the room with someone around to monitor it. The younger kids tend just to play education or flash games.

For the older ones I've used the built in time restrictions that the mac has to limit usage, otherwise they can get a bit obsessed.

Also, you can put limits on the network level to stop the teens using phones, iPad, and kindles late into the night. On school nights it cuts off earlier than the weekends.

Also, below a certain age they have to give up their passwords so sites online (Facebook etc) can be monitored. No different to real life really. We know their friends and friends parents, no reason not to keep an overview on their online activity.

However, in everything they have a large amount of freedom - it's not about censorship so much as it's about keeping them on a good path and not wandering too much.

Comment: I fear most older kids will be familiar with tools such as Chrome's Incognito mode, which makes tracking online activities much more difficult.

Comment: Track everything on the network level through the router. And yes, that might not get everything either. But, you're a parent, you can bluff. Or, just delete Chrome, etc.

Comment: Unless you have the time to go through the logs on the router, that's not going to work. A better approach is light filtering at the router along with time spent with your kids. Limit their internet use to appropriate hours and limited time.

Comment: There are products like KoalaSafe.com that work by creating a separate WiFi network for your children. You can choose the type of parenting you wish to use (blocking or allow freedom and get alerted to inappropriate use)

Answer (score 0):

I keep the computer in my room, so basically whenever, my 14 year step daughter wants to.use computer, she needs to sit near me and do her stuff.
Also, my.husband puts password in the computer, so my step daughter can.use it only when.we type the password. So, this way we can keep a check on how much time she spends on computer .
Also we encourage outdoor playing.
She gets an.hour or 2 hrs everyday at computer which.is more than enough.
Also we havent allowed her to be.on any social networking sites like Facebook or Instagram.
Once, she turns 16 , we will lower the restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Don't feel like a real answer, but too long and too much like an answer for a comment:

Monitoring (with technological measures, keystroke/screen/browsing history recording) what a child/teen does on a computer can be like reading their diaries, setting them up with an electronic/GPS bracelet and using hidden microphones to listen in to their private conversations with friends, all at once and even more. If you want to have *any* sane and trustful relationship with your child you shouldn't do it without their knowledge and after a certain age not at all. Just make sure they know the laws, the dangers and the moralities concerning the usual topics (copyright, anonymity, porn, whatever) and *talk* with them.

You can't prevent them from doing some mistakes and having some uncomfortable learning experiences, *like in every other area of life*.

(no parent here, young adult who was only ever restricted in the amount of time allowed to spend in front of computers. I learned about copy right law, I learned about porn, I learned about people trying to scam me - sure I saw some stuff I could have gone without. But that would only seriously trouble a child which is troubled anyway)

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple rule: media consumption should be made in public spaces. No TV or computers in their bedroom. Sure, I'm not always there, but they know they shouldn't do something they wouldn't do in public.

Answer (score -7):

Those people saying that kids internet usage should not be filtered are in for a life of pain, especially when their children develop mental problems, depression and addiction. Being liberal with your children and talking to them is not the same as opening the door and letting them into a porn shop and allowing them to browse the material whilst at the same time talking to them about the dangers of porn. I hope you don't learn the hard way that this stuff just shouldn't be available before a certain age, no matter what your moral persuasion.

Comment: Can you add some citation linking pornography exposure to "mental problems, depression and addiction"?

Comment: http://www.protectkids.com/effects/harms.htm

Comment: @AdamMills That article is not very convincing. It cites several studies that link pornography consumption with rape or violence. I would (provided the studies prevail under scrutiny) find that connection less than surprising: Individuals with a sex drive they find hard to control seem likely to be drawn to porn, and god only knows how much crime the availability of porn *prevented.* The connection does not establish a causal link.

Comment: I had unrestricted internet access and I ended up with a high paying job high self esteem, and a complete lack of mental problems or addiction.  Most of my childhood friends likewise had unsupervised internet access and shockingly they all seem to have survived as well.  Children aren't porcelain dolls that shatter the moment their exposed to life.  The reality of the world is that children *will* see porn as soon as they hit puberty, rather any of us like it short of locking them in the basement until 18 your not stopping it.  Your best bet is to accept that and prepare them for it.